# Understanding Marginal Rate of Substitutions given potential most utility

Tags: microeconomics, marginal

I have a homework question that says a consumer has utility function over two goods, apples (A) and bananas (B) given by:
U(A, B) = 3A + 5B.

It asks, "A consumer currently has 10 apples and 10 bananas. If their goal is to get the most possible utility, would they be willing to trade 5 apples for 4 bananas? or 5 apples for 2 bananas?

What is the minimum number of bananas the consumer would need to receive in exchange for 5
apples? I need to explain how these decisions relate to the marginal rate of substitution you found above.

So I found that A = 10 and B = 10. I then got U=10A+10B. The MRS I found for the utility function is MRS = 3/5. I don't understand how I would know which bundle creates the most utility. 3/5 means I need to give 5 bananas to receive 3 apples right? How would these relate to the marginal rate of substitution, 3/5? I can't find the price ratio here so how would I explain the relationship or trades?

After the previous question, I need to draw an indifference curve representing all of the bundles of apples and bananas where the consumer receives 15 and a utility of 30. How would I find which bundles receive 15 or 30? And find the intercepts for each axis points on the line. Do I need to solve for a linear equation or something?

MRS is so confusing conceptually. IC is confusing on how to graph them in accordance with the utility function or given utility.

Thank you!

Comment: "*So I found that A = 10 and B = 10. I then got U=10A+10B.*" How did you get to "U=10A+10B" from "U(A, B) = 3A + 5B" and "A = 10 and B = 10"?

Comment: "*I don't understand how I would know which bundle creates the most utility.*" It seems that you are having difficulties with the concepts. Do you have a textbook you can consult?

Comment: "*I need to draw an indifference curve representing all of the bundles of apples and bananas where the consumer receives 15*" not quite sure what you mean here.